# How to lock without turning the screen (monitor) off?

Tags: unity, power-management, monitor, lock-screen, lock

Due to a recent [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1372409), each time my screen turns off, I cannot get it back on.

Currently, the screen starts turning off after the computer is locked - which effectively means that I cannot lock my computer without having to completely restart it.

Is there a way to lock it, but without the monitor going to sleep/off?

Comment: See if this one helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/696738/prevent-monitor-from-losing-signal-after-screen-saver-lock-activates

Answer (score 2):

If you need or want a solution that prevents the screen to fall asleep, but that *does* dim/lock the screen after a while, there is another solution: instead of the system's own dim/lock option, use the script below to run in the background. You will need to install `xprintidle`.

How to set up:

- Disable all dim / lock options in System Settings. (In Brightness & lock **AND** in "Energy" settings)
- install xprintidle:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xprintidle
  ```
- Find your screen name; run in a terminal:

  ```
  xrandr
  ```

  Look for the name in the line where it says "connected". Your screen name could be for example `VGA-1` or `DVI-I-1`.
- Copy the script below, set the correct screen_name, the idle time before it should lock/dim the screen, and paste it into an empty file. Save it as`lock_dim.py`

*The script*

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import time

seconds = 600 # number of seconds to wait before lock/dim the screen
screen_name = "DVI-I-1" # example, replace it with your screen's name

awake = True

while True:
    curr_idle = subprocess.check_output(["xprintidle"]).decode("utf-8").strip()
    if awake == True:
        if int(curr_idle) > seconds*1000:
            command1 = "gnome-screensaver-command -l"
            command2 = "xrandr --output "+screen_name+" --brightness 0.1"
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command1])
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command2])
            awake = False
        else:
            pass
    elif awake == False:
        if int(curr_idle) > seconds*1000:
            pass
        else:
            command3 = "xrandr --output "+screen_name+" --brightness 1"
            subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", command3])
            awake = True
    time.sleep(2)
```

Test the script by opening a terminal and type:

```
python3 /path/to/lock_dim.py
```

If it works as you like, add it to your startup applications: Open Dash > "Startup Applications" > "Add", add the command:

```
python3 /path/to/lock_dim.py
```

Comment: unfortunately the command gnome-screensaver-command -l just turns the screen blank, showing the lock screen only for a second. How can I just get the lock screen? The huge nice clock.

Answer (score -2):

Go to **System preferences** > **Brightness & lock**, then change "Turn Screen off when inactive" to **Never**.

Now click on setting icon from top right click on you account username your screen will be locked and never sleep.

Comment: Actually it still starts fading the second I lock it, either by clicking Lock in the user menu, or using the keyboard shortcut.