# Display screensaver clock without asking for password or turning the screen black

Tags: gnome, lock-screen, screensaver

The command `gnome-screensaver -l` or with the option `-a` locks the screen and turns it black. I actually just want to see the screensaver (a huge nice clock). Currently I have a python script that makes use of gnome-screensaver -l from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/527423/304558). But it shows the locked screen only for a second or less and then the screen turns black. I've already set the "dim screen when inactive" setting in the power settings to off. What can I do to display the clock (see image) after a few minutes?

Currently the screen turns black after 1 minute and when I move the mouse, I can see the clock. But I want it to be displayed all the time when I'm idle.

[image]

Comment: What about the solution provided here: https://askubuntu.com/a/700163/631600

Comment: That doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible when you use Gnome screensaver. Since Gnome 2 it has lost almost all its features and now it can only lock screen and blank it ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Screensaver) even says that it should be called "screen blanker" rather than screensaver).

You can try XScreenSaver which is more powerful. To install it add the next packages: `xscreensaver`, `xscreensaver-data` and `xscreensaver-gl`. After the installation add it to your "Startup Applications". The command should be `xscreensaver -nosplash`. Check [this](https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-autostart-xscreensaver-ubuntu-16-04-16-10) link for the details and the pictures. `man xscreensaver` also contains valuable information.
Use `xscreensaver-demo` to start configuration window for XScreenSaver.

You have no need to uninstall `gnome-screensaver`, just disable it (you can revert all changes back later): `sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver`. Or rename it to `gnome-screensaver.bak`. You can also rename `gnome-screensaver-command` to `.bak` and make screen lock shortcut work with `xscreensaver` with this command:
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/xscreensaver-command /usr/bin/gnome-screensaver-command`
[Source](http://itnewscast.com/servers-storage/gnome3-replace-gnome-screensaver-xscreensaver)

Then you can use the standard GLText screensaver, which can display current date/time. Or you can browse https://www.gnome-look.org for some alternatives. [Here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1183056/) is nice flip-clock screensaver. There are more screensavers [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/search?projectSearchText=screensaver) and [here](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/231/order/latest).

Comment: Thank you. I installed xscreensaver and chose "GLText". In Advanced settings I'm using the command line `gltext -root -text '%A%n%d %b %Y%n%r' -no-wander -spin 0 -program 'date +"%H:%M Uhr %n%A, %d.%m.%Y %nWoche %W"'`. This gives me time and date plus the week number. It has no nice background, but at least it shows und updates the clock.

Comment: @Sadik That's good that my answer was useful. Sad that Gnome 3 is only a shadow of a former glory of its predecessor. This regards not only screensaver...